# Is there a driver for Canon MF4800?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 32-bit.

The machine detected the network printer Canon MF4800, but it can not find a driver.  The screen prompts for a driver.  I selected *Canon* but I cannot find the the series of my printer.  I went to the Canon website and searched for a Linux driver but drivers are not not available for the Linux OS.

Answer (score 2):

[There is a PPA for Canon printers](https://launchpad.net/%7Emichael-gruz/+archive/canon-trunk)

> PPA description - Canon printer driver daily
>
> Official drivers of Canon printers and multifunction devices, included versions 2.20 and newer

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu quantal main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu quantal main
```

---

- If you use 12.04 alter `quantal` in `precise`
- If you have question on how to use a PPA (or not know what they are) see
  [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: unfortunately that PPA only goes up to 14.10 (utopic).  But if you have 14.10 or lower, you can install it quickly by running `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk` at the command line.  I'm not sure which drivers you need to install after that or if the print wizard automatically uses the right one.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to get the mf4800 to work in Ubuntu with the following steps:

1. Get the drivers for the mf4890:

   `wget http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0100003440/06/Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V270_us_EN.tar.gz`
2. Install the requisite packages:

   `sudo apt-get install intltool libglade2-dev libxml2-dev libgtk2.0-dev libcups2-dev`
3. Extract the tarball and move into the necessary directory:

   `tar -xzf Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V270_us_EN.tar.gz`

   `cd Sources`

   `tar -xzf cndrvcups-common-2.70-1.tar.gz`

   `cd cndrvcups-common-2.70`

   `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`

   `cd ..`

   `sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_2.70-1_amd64.deb`
4. Repeat for the `lb` package:

   `tar -xzf cndrvcups-lb-2.70-1.tar.gz`

   `cd cndrvcups-lb-2.70`

   Edit the allgen.sh file and at line 37 remove `--enable-static --disable-shared`

   `sudo dh_shlibdeps --dpkg-shlibdeps-params=--ignore-missing-info`

   Edit the debian/rules file and add `--dpkg-shlibdeps-params=--ignore-missing-info` to the end of line 227. Edit debian/compat and make it 5 instead of 4.

   `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`

   `cd ..`

   `sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-lb_2.70-1_amd64.deb`

Comment: [reposted from a comment by user343008] This really works. I tried so many things for this without good results. This work I am printing well now. Thanks a lot. Only one thing to pay attention to, on the last step `dpkg-buildpackage -us` -uc I made for all the .deb files that were in the directory. And install the printer with port 9100. After change on properties socket://192.168.xx.xx:9100 to socket://192.168.xx.xx:515.