# Canon Pixma iP2850 printer problem

Tags: printing, canon

Recently I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 and tried to install a new-ish Canon iP2850 printer (wired USB connection) which works fine on Windows 7 and XP.  This printer is not in the Ubuntu list of drivers but the recommended (highlighted) driver was 'Canon iP2000 series'.

When trying to print nothing happens at the printer itself, but Ubuntu seems to think the job has gone through OK.

I downloaded a Linux driver from the Canon site, and it seems to be the same one as already included in Ubuntu (i.e. the above-mentioned 'iP2000 series driver').  So I'm not enthused about installing something that's probably already there and may not solve the problem.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: This method from the user that is not me posting here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/278284/is-there-a-driver-for-canon-mf4800 posted a generic answer and it has been confirmed as working.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the ip2788 driver. It works with iP2850 too. Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do this?